# How to get instanced object from particle system at location?

Tags: python, particles, animation-nodes, instances

I need to check which object is instanced at a certain location. The particle system spawns a collection of objects either as is or with the “Use Count” feature.

At the moment I found a way to get the locations with animation nodes, but couldn’t find a way to find out which of the collection objects is being spawned at that location.

[image]

Mabye there is a way to do it in python?

Thanks for the help!

This question is asociated with another question of mine: [How to get same hair particles from collection in second particle system/ or how to delete instanced particles without converting them to real meshes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163964/how-to-get-same-hair-particles-from-collection-in-second-particle-system-or-how)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a python solution to get all the instances in the depsgraph. By filtering with "is_instance" you can get the names of the instance object that corespond with the source objects.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context

dg = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

counter = 0
for i in dg.object_instances:
    obj = i.object
    print(obj.name)
    if not i.is_instance:
        print(f"Object {obj.name} at {i.matrix_world}")
    else:
        print(f"Instance of {obj.name} at {i.matrix_world}")
        counter += 1
print(f"Len of instanced objects: {counter}")
```

[image]
[image]